# MIPS: Does syscall 10 return 0?

Tags: c, assembly, mips

If I just wanted to translate this C code

```
int main(){
return 0;
}
```

into MIPS assembly code, would this work?

```
main:
li $v0 10
syscall
```

I know that syscall 10 exits, but would it also return 0?

Thanks for the help